# New job, I feel stupid

Tags: work-environment

Recently,  I got hired as a pharmacy technician at a mom and pop shop in my hometown.  I'm fresh out of school and don't have a lot of experience in a pharmacy. I like my new job because its a steady pace work environment and very laid back. I've made a few mistakes since I've started working but nothing extreme,  but the people I work with seem like they get frustrated when I do something wrong. Like yesterday I got back from lunch and there was five big boxes on the ground and one of the employees said put the prices on the medication and the first box I did already had prices on the label and I got the second box and it didn't but I put the labels on it and didn't put the price on it and put them up I was just confused but then the employee came over and told me to put the prices on it and acted kind of annoyed at me.  I also feel like an outcast no one tries to talk to me there and of I say something everyone ignores me. I feel like the employees also talk about me and they act like I'm an idiot. What should I do?

Comment: I'm sorry you're catching downvotes (and probably close votes.) That can't help you feel less stupid. The fact is your question isn't a good fit for us. We can't help you with your insecurity. Just know starting new jobs is hard. Being the new person who makes mistakes, to other people's ire, is hard. Learning a whole new career is hard. We just can't tell you what to do.

Comment: Welcome new user.  You know, it's a surprisingly common question on this site - "I'm new and feel the weight of it."   Maybe reading some of the many QA on here about it will help!   I'm sure you will do OK.

Comment: Tip: if you are confused, then **ask** your colleagues for help.

Comment: To add to the tip above, people really prefer an extra question to avoid a possibly expensive error... They might make a comment but questions are cheap... Hopefully some others on here will vote up your question...

Comment: In the section you describe what has happened with the boxes, you didn't put a lot of punctuation. This makes it hard for me to understand what exactly has happened.  Probably your question can still be answered without that detail, but it would help readability if you added some periods and commas.

Comment: answers in answers, please

Comment: @aaaaaa some of us have given answers as answers that get converted to comments - the reason tends to be that the answer is too short... perhaps we lack the skill of using 17 words when one will do...

Answer (score 2):

Everyone makes mistakes; even people who are great at their job do. Try to not take it so hard; that serves no purpose and only stresses you out (which makes it more likely you will make mistakes).

What you do need to do is learn from your mistakes and apologize when you make them. As far as your coworkers and their attitude, if you do the above, it will almost certainly work out in fairly short time.

Answer (score 0):

Be open and friendly and try to do the best that you can.

The other employee is likely annoyed at you because they feel that they gave you a simple instruction and you didn't follow it. This could be your fault due to some misunderstanding or it might be their fault due to insufficiently clear instructions (both of these things are ok and not a big deal). Unfortunately, some people tend not to see their own flaws and will blame you for their own mistakes or overly criticize you for trivial errors because they don't necessarily recognise/remember their own trivial errors.

This isn't fair but you can't change that. The best you can do is remember that people are flawed and that they will behave better to you on average if you are friendly and helpful.

Likewise, making friends often requires a bit of effort on both sides. New work places can be intimidating which will make it seem harder to make the first move. Ideally your colleagues should realise this and go out of their way to speak to you. Unfortunately, this requires a bit of effort for them to a) realise and b) go over to speak to you. Hence, people might not do this because they are busy, tired, shy or just flat out lazy. This means that you might have to approach them, even if it is intimidating.